# Twig shows extra fields

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I have a simple form which looks like this

```
.......
$builder  
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'text'
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

What I want is to render only the name field

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'role': 'form', 'novalidate' : 'novalidate'} }) }}

{{ form_label(form.name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
{{ form_errors(name.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}

{{ form_end(form)
```

As result I get the page rendered with both name and email fields. What I'm doing wrong and how to prevent rendering of email field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In according with the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables), if you don't want to render unrendered fields, you can use:

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If your field is not required, you can do :

```
{{ form_label(form.email, null, {'label_attr': {'class':'hidden'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control hidden'} }) }}
{{ form_errors(name.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control hidden'} }) }}
```

Hope this helps.